# Slider's width isn't updating without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

When the page resizes "sliderContainerWidth" sticks with the same width, but if i refresh the page on any width its works fine.. I've tried using resize event as u guys can see i couldn't fixed it. It's not updating without refreshing the page..

```
let counter = 0;
const back = document.querySelector("#back");
const next = document.querySelector("#next");
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector("#slider-container");
var sliderContainerWidth =
  document.querySelector("#slider-container").clientWidth;

const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
const max = document.querySelectorAll(".slide").length - 1;



window.addEventListener("resize", sliderFunc);
next.addEventListener("click", sliderFunc);
function sliderFunc() {
  if (counter < max) {
    counter++;
    slider.style.left = "-" + sliderContainerWidth * counter + "px";
  } else {
    counter = 0;
    slider.style.left = "-" + sliderContainerWidth * counter + "px";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", backEvent);
back.addEventListener("click", backEvent);

function backEvent() {
  if (counter >= 1) {
    counter--;
    slider.style.left = "-" + sliderContainerWidth * counter + "px";
  } else {
    counter = max;
    slider.style.left = "-" + sliderContainerWidth * counter + "px";
  }
}

//mousevnt
let timer = setInterval(sliderFunc, 12000);

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  timer = setInterval(sliderFunc, 12000);
});

//mousevnt
```

Comment: Could you include the CSS and the HTML in your question?

Comment: Have you tried just putting a console.log('foo') in both the backEvent and sliderFunc. Can you check if the resize event is firing or not? If so, then the problem is something with your sliderFunc logic

Comment: @Cameron Yeah resize event is working. I've tried  console.log("..") in it and works fine, keep updating

Comment: @acarlstein yeah i did :)

Comment: Are you specifically talking about the variable `sliderContainerWidth`. That value only ever gets set once when you load the page because you never set the value again. If you want to update that variable, you need to set it again in your `sliderFunc` or `backEvent` functions. It doesn't update values magically

Comment: @Cameron So its fixable ? I'm gonna try what you say, i published all the code can you please try also

Comment: Well, if you're just trying to get the var `sliderContainerWidth` to update, this should work. Can confirm it myself. You can log the value to see it yourself. But again, I don't know if that's what you're trying to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, you need to update the value inside of your event functions. It will not update if it's not getting set. The reason it only gets set when you refresh is because all the top-level javascript gets read when the page first loads.

```
function sliderFunc() {
  if (counter < max) {
    counter++;
    slider.style.left = "-" + sliderContainerWidth * counter + "px";
  } else {
    counter = 0;
    slider.style.left = "-" + sliderContainerWidth * counter + "px";
  }
  sliderContainerWidth = document.querySelector("#slider-container").clientWidth;
}
```

Comment: Great! Can you give me the green checkmark

Comment: I think this can be simplify by doing: ```counter = (counter < max) ? counter + 1 : 0;
slider.style.left = `-${sliderContainerWidth * counter}px`;
sliderContainerWidth = document.querySelector("#slider-container").clientWidth;```